# Is there a callback to use to tell when the user's location is available

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, core-location

I'm after a callback or protocol that will notify me when the user's location is available. So that when a user's location is found I can zoom into where they are. What can I use to do this?

I was thinking there waas something in CoreLocation that could do it, but I can't find how to do it.

[Update]

I've implemented `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>` with `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` and created an CLLocationManager instance.

```
locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

but I'm still not getting any location updates. Also if I use `didUpdateLocation:` then it will re-zoom to the user each update. Is there a better way than having a check to see if it's the first update?

[Update 2]
adding `self.` to the `locationManager` got it going and I checked to see if `fromLocation:` is `nil` to tell if it was the first update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol, specifically `-locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`. You can get the accuracy of the location reading from the `newLocation` parameter's `horizontalAccuracy` property.

Comment: How do I assign my class as the delegate once the protocol has been implemented?

Comment: Congratulations on 101 answers Noah